# Migrate 100+ virtual machines from on-prem to azure

Tags: migration, azure-virtual-machine

Apologies if this is the wrong platform for this question.

If I want to migrate 100 VM's onto Azure VM's what all things I need to consider and how can I migrate?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a comprehensive answer but some things to consider are:
- Start with a thorough inventory of the VMs to migrate. Issues to watch out for include..
  - Any unsupported OS versions, including 32-bit.
  - large numbers of attached drives.
  - Disk drives >1TB.
  - Gen 2 VHDs.
  - Application and network interdependencies which need to be maintained.
  - Specific performance requirements (i.e. any VMs that would need Azure premium storage, SSD drives etc.).

In developing a migration strategy some important considerations are:
- How much downtime can you tolerate? To minimize downtime look at solutions like Azure Site Recovery which supports rapid switchover. If downtime is more flexible there are more offline migration tools and scripts available.
- Understand whether to move to the new Azure Resource Manager or the Service Management deployment model. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/.
- Which machines to move first (pick the simplest, with fewest dependences).
- Consider cases where it may be easier to migrate the data or application to a new VM rather than migrate the VM itself).
A good forum to ask specific migration questions is: [Microsoft Azure Site Recovery](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=hypervrecovmgr)

Answer (score 0):

Appending to sendmarsh's reply

The things you will have to consider are:
Version of virtual environment i.e VMWare or Hyper-V.
Os version, RAM Size, OS disk size, OS disk count, Number of disks, Capacity of each disk, format of hard disk, number of processor cores,number of NIC's, processor architecture, Network configurations such as IP address's, generation type if the environment is Hyper-V.
I could have missed a few more things... like checking if the VMWare tools are installed. Some of the configurations are not supported like having an iSCSI disk will not be supported. Microsoft supports not all naming conventions for the machines, so be careful in setting the name as that might affect things later.
A full length of pre-requisites list is over at: 
    [1]: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/site-recovery-best-practices/#azure-virtual-machine-requirements

Update: Using Powershell to automate the migration would make your life easier.